# Android app crashing on calling SQLiteHelper

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have been using this tutorial for some part, but I had to make some little changes and my app crashes on mobile phone. There are no errors in code, though!
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

```
public class SQLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SP = "SP";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ST = "ST";

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SPT.db";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
         " (" +
        COLUMN_NAME_SP + " text not null" +
        COLUMN_NAME_ST + " text not null" +
        " )";

    public SQLiteDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(SQLiteDbHelper.class.getName(),
          "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
      database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

}
```

And then, later on, I have this code for a method for button click:

```
            public void Save(View view){
            String st = editTextSt.getText().toString();
            String sp = editTextSp.getText().toString();

       //this is what makes my app crash [beginning]
            SQLiteDbHelper database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = database2.getWritableDatabase();
       //this is what makes my app crash [end]

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP, sp);
    values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ST, st);
    long insertId = database.insert(SQLiteDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
```

Comment: Can you add your logcat output? it would be helpfull to identify the problem

Comment: Provide the Logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to place comma`(,)` after every column name in create table query change it as:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
         " (" +
        COLUMN_NAME_SP + " text not null, " +
        COLUMN_NAME_ST + " text not null " +
        ");";
```

Comment: Thanks! So small problem, so much trouble! Will accept your answer as a solution as soon as I'll be able to! Thanks again!